# Archivo ZIP a byte[] en PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, zip

Quiero enviar un archivo zip a un web service SOAP, para ponerlo en el xml me piden que lo transforme a un array de bytes. He intentado varias cosas pero, al parecer, no funcionan. En visual basic se puede así:

```
Dim B() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("")
```

En PHP habrá algo similar?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento con PHP?

Comment: No me queda claro: la comunicación con el `WebService`, ¿es mediante un script PHP? ¿convertirás el `array` en PHP? ¿La etiqueta de VB.NET entonces porque sería?

Comment: Puse ese código en VB.NET porque quería saber si había un equivalente en PHP. Estoy consumiendo un web service SOAP en un script PHP. Me pide enviar un archivo xml comprimido en un zip, en la documentación de este web service me dice que lo convierta a byte[] (el zip). En pocas palabras, el web service me pdide que envie dos parámetros: El nombre del archivo y el mismo archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente un String de PHP es compatible con un byte array en .NET.

```
$byteArr = file_get_contents('file.zip');
```

Y puedes enviar la variable byteArr al web service aunque dependiendo de la especificación del Web Service probablemente tengas que codificarla antes con Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, logré averiguar que este códgio en VB.NET

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("archivo.zip")
```

Es equivalente en PHP a

```
$handle = fopen("archivo.zip", "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize("archivo.zip"));
fclose($handle);
$b= unpack("C*",$contents);
```

Gracias a todos por responder.